# How do I get Extra Information from MyFirebaseInstanceIdService class?

Tags: android

I'm implementing Firebase Cloud Messaging and It's driving me crazy with a lot of trouble. I want to update the token everytime the user logs in, so when the users logs in I made a Service which delete the token and creates a new one. So the method onrefreshToken is called. And now what I want is to save the user, the idDevice and the token on database, but I don't know how to do it, because this service(MyFirebaseInstanceIdService) is never created, so I haven't put an extra.

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("myFireBase", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String refreshedToken) {        
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String idDevice = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        // Token token = new Token(refreshedToken, idDevice, usuario);
        // Call server to save the token
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FirebaseInstanceIdService  will call only ones when app will instrall so save on sharedpreference on first time and get value from shared preference  on login time.
use like this.

```
  public class FirebaseService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override

public void onTokenRefresh() {

    String Tocken_Refresh= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getApplication().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCESGCM, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("fcm",Tocken_Refresh);

    editor.commit();

 }
}
```

Comment: I tried something like that, the problem is as it's an asynchronous process, the result gived me null, because we can't know when the function onTokenRefresh finishes. So when I tried to get the string from sharedpreferences was too fast and I hasn't finished in saving it

Comment: actualy first time when app will instrall only you will get tocken when this class will hit  or call  it will definatily save tocken   and this class  will never call lifetime untim you didnt update your app or reintralll new fresh app

Comment: after  instraling app first it will call that service classs ones class called it will  not until you diidnt deleate app

Comment: Sorry I don't understand all the stuff, let me summarize it. At loginActivity I have this:
1. Destroy token
2. Create token so refreshToken is called
3. I get the new token from sharedpreferences

So the thing is that step 3 is doing earlier than 2 because of the asynchronization

Comment: loook  

The onTokenRefresh() method is going to be called whenever a new token is generated. Upon app install, it will be generated immediately (as you have found to be the case). It will also be called when the token has changed.

Comment: so every time when tocken generate save in shared prefrence  and do code for  sent to server

Comment: if you force to genrate on login time it will get null tocken

Comment: Exactly I can but what I'm trying to do is controlling the order: i want to destroy, create and get the new token and I can't because the generation of the token is asynchronous, so thats my problem. So thats why I tried to save the data in the server in the refreshToken because Its the only place I know when the token has been generated but there I don't have the user name, and that was the question.

Comment: Ah, maybe It's what you mean, could I save the user name in loginActivity on SharedPreferences and then onRefreshToken get it with the getString?

Comment: first get tocken when app instrall then get tocken fromshared prerence store in string and send to your server this value from anywhere in you app because you have  tocken stored in your shared prefrence

Comment: And are you totally sure that when I get the token stored from preference It won't give me null because It has done later?

Comment: Ya this is my live app code I had fached same problem I worked more than 10 days for gcm to fcm

Comment: Sorry again, but i really want to destroy the token manually(it can be done with a function) because I need to control the tokens to be generated just in the log in, thats why i generate everytime a user logs in. Your tip is great when there is no delete, but in my case i delete it so thats why I have 2 registered tokens, the first when app is installed and the next when the user logs in, and this is the token I want

Comment: Sorry to say but I search idiint found any  such type of method

Comment: This is: FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId(); so after this If I use             FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(); it calls refreshToken again

Comment: Do one this you r storing to server tocken just delete tocken from your database

Comment: Sorry I didn't tried ok tnanks I will also try that

Comment: I m storing in db tocken when I don't want I m deleting